"Invalid file name" error when changing product view configuration in admin panel for Porto theme
in admin/stores/configuration/Product View I made changes to the Page Layout and Product Image Size (localhost). However, when pressing "Save Config" I get "Invalid file name" and no changes are saved.

I have no idea what file it is talking about - I only changed the settings in the Page Layout and Product Image Size dropdowns. Any ideas?
I tried flushing the cache and a setup:upgrade as part of the usual troubleshooting.

Try searching the files for the error message "Invalid file name". I tried searching in the core files but I found nothing. I mean I found some occurrences but they look different. Maybe you have a custom module doing this

Check magento log file for this, it will give you detail idea for the error.

No relevant magento log, unfortunately...

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/39222

Most likely you don't have the necessary media files (pictures for example). Try to set the debugger break point on vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/File.php line 285 and execute the expression from line 283:
$this->_getUploadDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($value)

and you will see the path to the file that causes the error.
Example on the screen

